# Animate TextViews one by one in Queue

Tags: android, animation, textview, android-animation

Background: I have some View with some dynamically added TextViews. It is like a graph/tree implementation where each TextView is a graph. I am maintaining an adjacency list of these TextViews(their ids are maintained and then I can findViewById).

What I want: I have a play button. I want to animate the TextViews such that I see the root, then its children, then the next level.
What I know: I have made them invisible on pressing of play button. I am doing a BFS such that

```
Put root TextView in Queue
make it visible
Put all the direct children of root in a Queue
while(!Q.isempty())
{
    remove the first element from Queue
    // animate
    // after end of animation loop through the adjacency list of this node 
    // and put all of its children in the queue
}
```

Problem: Whatever we try, the first element gets removed, the Q is populated again with children and then the animation of all the elements in qeueue starts at once and finishes at once.
In other words, the animation doesn't start till the code finishes.
I have tried putting the code for population of the children in the onAnimationEnd of an AnimationListener. Doesn't work. Tried Thread.sleep, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your problem is that you treat `startAnimation()` method as sync, which should finish only after animation finishes. But it is async: `startAnimation()` just changes view's state, telling him to start animate himself at the next UI redraw loop, and immediately goes further. That's why in your app all animations are executed simultaneously. `Thread.sleep()` also won't work because it just freezes UI thread not changing its behavior logic.

Solution can be the following:

it is possible to specify delay, which view should wait before actually starting animation, by `setStartOffset(offset)` method of `Animation` object. If each your animation longs, for example, 500 ms, so `Animation` object for root view should have start offset 0, for its children - 500, for their children - 1000 etc.

You need to create list of `Animation` objects with clones of initial animation, set their start offsets and pass to corresponding views.

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim...); // load initial animation from xml

List<Animation> anims = new ArrayList<Animation>;
for (int i=0; i < treeDepth; i++){
    anims.set(i, anim.clone());
    anims.get(i).setStartOffset(anim.getDuration() * i);
    for (...){
        // here you apply just created animation to all children of i-th level,
        // it can be done later, no difference
        view.startAnimation(anims.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is my first android project, so I am a bit unaware of the animation stuff. What are we supposed to write in the xml? Right now all I want is the TextViews to become visible again (I made them invisible by text_view_obj.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE))

Comment: @user2759617 no problem! we all faced with similar problems at the beginning ) Android is more event-based, so understanding its behavior logic will take some time.

Comment: @user2759617 in code sample, I'm using `loadAnimation` factory method to load animation from xml, but you can create Animation object programmatically. Another point: to set true invisibility it's better to use `View.GONE`, because views, that were set to invisible with `View.INVISIBLE`, still occupy room in layout and can accept touches!

Comment: Guide to creating animations using xml is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween  You need `Tween animation` section.

Answer (score 0):

See this My splash screen Animation, one after another

my Layout with some views

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_bg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_background" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageCircle"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/circle_bg_1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageSale"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/avsave_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

translate_from_left_to_right animation in res/anim/translate_from_left_to_right.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="50%" />
```

translate_from_right_to_left animation in res/anim/translate_from_right_to_left.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="-50%" />
```

zoom_out animation in res/anim/zoom_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXScale="1.5"
    android:fromYScale="1.5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1" >

</scale>
```

and finally here is my SplashActivity.java file

```
package com.av.stores;

imprt android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
private ImageView imgCircle, imgSale;
private ImageView imgSplashBg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {

    imgCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageCircle);
    imgSale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSale);
    imgSale.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imgCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    imgSplashBg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_bg);


    Animation zoomAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_out);
    final Animation animLeftToRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.translate_left_to_right);

    final Animation animRightToLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.translate_right_to_left);

    imgSplashBg.startAnimation(zoomAnim);

    zoomAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            imgCircle.startAnimation(animLeftToRight);
        }
    });

    animLeftToRight.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            imgSale.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgSale.startAnimation(animRightToLeft);

        }
    });

    animRightToLeft.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                /*
                 * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful
                 * when you want to show case your app logo / company
                 */

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    /*Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_enter,
                            R.anim.activity_leave);*/
                    finish();
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    });

    super.onStart();
}
}
```